# Can't find a module created by me in nodejs running in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

This is my command line, routes is a module and is being imported and exported properly since it works on a different computer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your error mean that `Node.js` cant locate the specified modules,
you can also check that the file path specified in the `require()` is correct, so make sure that `./routes.js` is in the same directory as `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

You check index.js file and require `./routes/<file_name>` to require file of routes folder you want